# Copying files, skipping alert window 'are you sure message'

Tags: c#, file, move

My C# console program copies 2 folders into 1. It works but I am new to C#. I cant figure out how I make the program skip the alert window "are you sure you want to overwrite the files".

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MirrorSystem {
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string source1 = @"folder1";
        string source2 = @"folder2";
        string destination = @"destination";
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting..");
            FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source1, destination, UIOption.AllDialogs);
            FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source2, destination, UIOption.AllDialogs);

            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Environment.Exit(0);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Canceled!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have your tried removing the "AllDialogs" argument?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the value `true` as the third (overwrite) parameter. Here is the official documentation for the method:

```
public static void CopyDirectory(
    string sourceDirectoryName,
    string destinationDirectoryName,
    bool overwrite
)
```

The description of the overwrite parameter:

> **overwrite**
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> **True** to *overwrite* existing files;
> otherwise **False**. Default is **False**.

[Source.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127958(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found that already but wasnt able to integrate it into the program.

Comment: Could you help me with integrating this into the program? I really dont know what else to try.. :)

Comment: Try to replace "UIOption.AllDialogs" with "true" and see if it works.

Comment: Yea it works. But i want it to show the progress bar. Is that possible at all? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use method File.Copy --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx

The third parameter allows you to specify whether you should or should not overwrite existing files with the same name in the destination folder.